# Problem with positioning div in css

Tags: css

I have a problem with css.
I have (parent) div and inside, another (child) div.
I want align inner (child) div to the TOP-RIGHT corner of the (parent) div.

```
<div id="parent">

    <div id="child">
    </div>

</div>
```

I need something like:

```
#child{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right 0;
}
```

but this css code puts my "child" div into top-right corner of body element!

Please help, TNX! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your parent container needs to be set as relative positioning.

```
#parent {position:relative}
#child {position:absolute; top:0; right:0}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the style of #parent to `position: relative`

Answer (score 0):

```
#parent{ 
 background-color:#FF0000;
   position: absolute;
   height:200px;
   width:500px;
}


#child{ 
 background-color: #3300FF;
  position: absolute; 
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
  top: 0; 
  right:0;
} 

<div id="parent" >div1 
    <div id="child">DIV2
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#child{ 
  float:right; 
} 

<div id="parent" >Parent
    <div id="child">Child
    </div> 
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```